# How do you figure out parent and child relations between pages in gatsbyjs?

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby

**UPDATE: 02-09-2020**
I've opened up an issue at https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/26752

---

**Is there any logical and easy way to tell gatsby that a given page in a sub folder is a child page?**

I know that if you put pages in sub folders under `/src/pages/subpages`, gatsby will produce a route under the given folder like:

```
/src/pages/page-01.js
/src/pages/page-02/index.js
/src/pages/page-02/child-page-of-02
```

will give you:

```
http://localhost:8000/page-01
http://localhost:8000/page-02
http://localhost:8000/page-02/child-page-of-02
```

Now, I've tried to easily fill a sidebar with page links and wanted to indent the child pages.
To do so I've used the query:

```
query MyQuery {
  allSitePage {
    nodes {
      id
      children {
        id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The results were:

```
{
  "data": {
    "allSitePage": {
      "nodes": [
        {
          "id": "SitePage /page-01",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "id": "SitePage /dev-404-page/",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "id": "SitePage /",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "id": "SitePage /page-02/",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "id": "SitePage /page-02/child-page-of-02/",
          "children": []
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "extensions": {}
}
```

As you can see, the children array is empty. Which is not what I was expecting.
I am expecting this output:

```
        {
          "id": "SitePage /page-02/",
          "children": ["SitePage /page-02/child-page-of-02/"]
        },
        {
          "id": "SitePage /page-02/child-page-of-02/",
          "children": []
        }
```

Has anyone got this working? If yes, how?
I did already lookup in the docs but could not find anything useful...

Nothing in: [Page Creation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/page-creation/) and [Node Creation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/node-creation/)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I ended up making a plugin myself to meet my needs, it is called `gatsby-plugin-better-page-tree`  you can find it here: https://github.com/dream-bit-de/gatsby-plugin-better-page-tree.

---

**Short How-To:**

gatsby-plugin-better-page-tree will generate the relations like this: `/src/pages/subpages`,

```
/src/pages/parentpage/index.js
/src/pages/parentpage/subpage/index.js
```

will now give you:

```
{
  "node": {
    "id": "PageTree-parentpage-id-8496bef7-3809-4fac-8f97-ab2b98b7f54d",
    "name": "Parentpage",
    "pathRaw": "/parentpage/",
    "pathNoTrail": "/parentpage",
    "isparentpage": true,
    "children": [
      {
        "id": "PageTree-parentpage/subpage-id-bc8cec01-3f85-47d2-aec9-2e3ddc76df32",
        "name": "Subpage",
        "pathRaw": "/parentpage/subpage/",
        "pathNoTrail": "/parentpage/subpage"
      }
    ]
  },
  "node": {
    "id": "PageTree-parentpage/subpage-id-bc8cec01-3f85-47d2-aec9-2e3ddc76df32",
    "name": "Subpage",
    "pathRaw": "/parentpage/subpage/",
    "pathNoTrail": "/parentpage/subpage",
    "isparentpage": false,
    "children": []
  }
}
```

Just use `npm install @dream-bit-de/gatsby-plugin-better-page-tree` or `yarn install @dream-bit-de/gatsby-plugin-better-page-tree`, it's your choice.
After that you have to modify your `gatsby-config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `Your Super Gatsby Site!`,
    description: `I love Gatsby!`,
    author: `Community,`,
    siteUrl: `https://www.my-gatsby-site-yeeehaaaw.com/`
  },
  plugins: [
    // ... other plugins
    `@dream-bit-de/gatsby-plugin-better-page-tree`
  ]
};
```

To use this for example in a sidebar you have to use it like this:

`sidebar.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link, useStaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby';

function Sidebar() {
  const Pages = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query {
      allPageTree {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            name
            pathRaw
            pathNoTrail
            isRootPage
            children {
              id
              ... on PageTree {
                id
                name
                pathRaw
                pathNoTrail
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `);
  const { nodes } = Pages.allSitePage;

return (
     {nodes.map((n) => (
     <ul key={`sidebar-${n.id}`}>
      <li>
       <Link to={n.pathRaw}>
        <span>{n.name}</span>
        {
         n.children && n.children.length > 0 ? (
         {nodes.map((n) => (
          <ul key={`sidebar-${n.id}`}>
            <li>
              <Link to={n.pathRaw}>
                <span>{n.name}</span> 
              </Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
         ) : null
        }
       </Link>
      </li>
     </ul>
     ))}
);
```

That's it!

**Be aware that the query will give you all pages in the first place! You have to make sure that no duplicates will show up in your sidebar, if that is what you need.**